# How to make R read data separated by "|**|"

Tags: r, read.table

I have a large data set, which variables are separated by the symbol of `|**|`.  I've tried to use `sep="|"`, but this did not work when the one of the string variables containing `|`.  How can I make R to read data with compound separator?

Comment: Are you saying that you have unquoted strings that contain a | in your data? Please give a pathological example of your input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Frankly I think it would be easier to do this with sed. This may not be very fast in R)

```
Lines <- readLines(filename)
sLines <- strsplit(Lines, "|**|", fixed=TRUE) # Thanks, Richie.
dat <- read.table(text= sapply(sLines, paste, collapse=",") ,sep=",")
```

Here's the test on a simple datastring:

```
Lines <- "a|**|b|**|c\nd|**|e|**|f"
sLines <- strsplit(Lines, "\\|\\*\\*\\|")
dat <- read.table(text= sapply(sLines, paste, collapse=",") ,sep=",")
dat
#-----------
  V1 V2 V3
1  a  b  c
2  d  e  f
```

`strsplit` uses regex patterns so you need to doubly escape the "specials". Would be faster if you used `colClasses` in the read.table call. See `?read.table`

Comment: You can get `strsplit` to split on a fixed string rather than a regular expression by passing `fixed = TRUE`.

Comment: I'm guessing your solution is faster than `gsub('|**|','<TAB>',data)` followed by a `strsplit` or a `readLines` call to the output?

Comment: I don't know. You would need the fixed parameter to be TRUE to get that to succeed.